# How to select and each in Xml child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to use jQuery.each() method on XML child elements.

Below is my code.

```
$(function() {
    var xml = "<approvalcontent><vac_applier>Name</vac_applier><vac_sdate>2017-02-03</vac_sdate><vac_edate>2017-02-10</vac_edate><vac_reason>kind</vac_reason></approvalcontent>";
    bindContent(xml);
});

function bindContent(xml) {
    $(xml).find("approvalcontent").children().each(function(){
        alert("here!");
    });
}
```

But this each function shows anything.
I want to roof as much as Xml  elements.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `find()` only works for descendants, your `<approvalcontent>` element is a root element, so what you wanted was probably `filter()` instead

```
$(xml).filter("approvalcontent")...
```

You should however be parsing the XML before accessing it, as that would give you an actual valid XML document to work with, and you could use `find()`

```
function bindContent(xml) {
    var parsed = $.parseXML(xml);
    $(parsed).find("approvalcontent").children().each(function() {
        alert("here!");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$(xml).children()`

```js
$(function() {
  var xml = "<approvalcontent><vac_applier>Name</vac_applier><vac_sdate>2017-02-03</vac_sdate><vac_edate>2017-02-10</vac_edate><vac_reason>kind</vac_reason></approvalcontent>";
  bindContent(xml);
});

function bindContent(xml) {
  $(xml).children().each(function() {
    console.log("here!");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) as `approvalcontent` is at top level.

```js
$(function() {
  var xml = "<approvalcontent><vac_applier>Name</vac_applier><vac_sdate>2017-02-03</vac_sdate><vac_edate>2017-02-10</vac_edate><vac_reason>kind</vac_reason></approvalcontent>";
  bindContent(xml);
});

function bindContent(xml) {
  $(xml).filter("approvalcontent").children().each(function() {
    alert("here!");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(xml).children()` will suffice